# How can I change the value of a property on the call of a reusable component on Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a modal with a form where I am attempting to render a component which could be use anywhere with different output.

For example:

This is the component:

```
import { Select, SelectItem } from 'carbon-components-react';
import React from 'react';
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { uniqBy } from 'lodash';
import GetShipmentsAddresses from './containers/GetShipmentsAddresses';

const AddressesSelect = ({ t, handleAddresses, value }) => (
  <GetShipmentsAddresses>
    {({ data }) => {
      const unique = uniqBy(data, 'originationAddress.description');
      const renderAddresses = unique.map(addresses => (
        <SelectItem
          value={addresses.originationAddress.description}
          key={addresses.id}
          text={addresses.originationAddress.description}
        />
      ));
      return (
        <Select
          id="select-3"
          defaultValue="Shipped From"
          labelText={t('shipments.shippedFrom')}
          onChange={handleAddresses}
        >
          <SelectItem
            disabled
            hidden
            value=""
            text={t('shipments.selectLocation')}
          />
          <SelectItem value="" text={t('shipments.allLocations')} />
          {renderAddresses}
        </Select>
      );
    }}
  </GetShipmentsAddresses>
);

AddressesSelect.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  handleAddresses: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default translate()(AddressesSelect);
```

And I need to call that on a parent component like this:

```
const ParentComp = ({ VALUE }) => (

          <AddressesSelect
            handleAddresses={this.handleChange('shippedFrom')}
            VALUE="originationAddress" // this is would be VALUE
            title={t('shipments.shippedFrom')}
          />

          <br />

          <AddressesSelect
            handleAddresses={this.handleChange('shippedTo')}
            VALUE="destinationAddress" // this is would be VALUE
            title={t('shipments.shippedFrom')}
          />

)
```

So, the only thing that is going to change from call to the other is that instead of saying `addresses.originationAddress.description` it has to say `addresses.destinationAddress.description`

The only word changing is going to be `originationAddress` to `destinationAddress`.

So let's say I will like to do something like this:

```
const AddressesSelect = ({ t, handleAddresses, VALUE }) => (
  <GetShipmentsAddresses>
    {({ data }) => {
      const unique = uniqBy(data, 'VALUE.description');
      const renderAddresses = unique.map(addresses => (
        <SelectItem
          value={addresses.VALUE.description}
          key={addresses.id}
          text={addresses.VALUE.description}
        />
      ));
      return (
        <Select
          id="select-3"
          defaultValue="Shipped From"
          labelText={t('shipments.shippedFrom')}
          onChange={handleAddresses}
        >
          <SelectItem
            disabled
            hidden
            value=""
            text={t('shipments.selectLocation')}
          />
          <SelectItem value="" text={t('shipments.allLocations')} />
          {renderAddresses}
        </Select>
      );
    }}
  </GetShipmentsAddresses>
);
```

Where `VALUE` could be change in the call of the component to `destinationAddress` or `originationAddress`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use template strings

```
   const ParentComp = ({ value }) => (
          <AddressesSelect
            handleAddresses={this.handleChange('shippedFrom')}
            VALUE={`${value}Address`} // this is would be VALUE
            title={t('shipments.shippedFrom')}
          />)
```

and in your component use it as

```
        <SelectItem
          value={addresses[value].description}
          key={addresses.id}
          text={addresses[value].description}
        />
```

just like dot notation you can use **address['originatingAddress']** and here you can just replace it with your **value** variable

Comment: Can you be more clear? Like I know what a template string is. But can you elaborate a bit more your answer.